# podman. Change status from running container to created status

Tags: podman

i just created a cointainer via podman but after a while (within 2 hours normally) the container changed the status from UP to CREATE and it is not more running.
In the log file there are no errors.

I started the container also with restart option, but it seems not works.
This is the command I used to start the container.

> podman run -d --name igfsbuynow -p 18081:18081 -p 18080:18080 --restart=always igfsbuynow:5.5.0.17

Podman version is: 4.0.2  and system is:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa)

What I need, is that the container remains always up and running.
Could you please indicate to me how to avoid that container changed the status from UP to CREATED?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have the exact same issue.  in my case the container is an nginx instance. same podman and RHEL version.  driving me insane.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73206224/podman-change-status-from-running-container-to-created-status Did you get an answer ti this? I am in similar situation.